# Using baseUrl in jsconfig.json is not working with Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

[jsconfigerror](https://github.com/hutber/jsconfigerror) is an example repository showing the jsconfig is not working.

I have the following set inside my *jsconig.json* file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```

However, when I do an import, it fails:

```
./pages/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/AThing' in '/var/www/gd.hutuber.com/pages'
```

Folder Structure

```
¬ components
   ¬ AThing
¬ pages
   ¬ index.js
```

### pages/index.js

```
import Head from 'components/AThing'
```

How can I get `baseUrl` to work with Next.js?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since [Next.js 9.4](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-4), Next.js automatically supports the *tsconfig.json* and *jsconfig.json* "paths" and "baseUrl" options.

Read more in the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases).

---

For prior versions, Next.js doesn't read the configurations written in file *jsconfig.json*. You have to customize the [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) configuration the Next.js way.

Create a file named *next.config.js* at the root directory of your project next to file *package.json*. Then restart.

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  webpack: config => {
    config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve('./'))

    return config
  }
}
```

Comment: While correct at some point, since Next 9.4 both `tsconfig.json` and `jsconfig.json` file `compilerOptions.baseUrl` and `compilerOptions.paths` are supported: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases (as shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61838859/2224331))

Comment: @SidOfc Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 23):

From Next.js 9.4 onward, you can easily create the *jsconfig.json* or *tsconfig.json files in the root of your project and then simply enter following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

Next thing you must do is to import your component like following:

```
import Head from 'components/AThing';
```

*Assuming components folder placed in the root of your project as well.*

Answer (score 11):

Before starting, you should check that your Next.js version is at least 9.4.

When you configure the *jsconfig.json*, you should kill the process and restart.

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@components/*": ["components/*"],
        "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      }
    }
  }
```

While *baseUrl* is useful and it is enough for most of the cases, you can use the prefix @ to be clear that is an aliases folder.

Be sure that, when you import something, you do not start with `./`, like `./pages/index.js`, because you are breaking the absolute alias and start to import in relative mode.

```
import Head from '@components/AThing'
```

Comment: Restarting the process was the answer! Thanks, man.

Comment: Are you sure its name is *"jsconig.json"*?

Comment: Sorry it's "jsconfig.json", there was a typo, thank you.

Comment: I did this (with Next13) and my hot-reload is not detecting changes on the `@alias` I created. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Did you kill the process and restart it?

Answer (score 3):

Create file *jsconfig.json* in the root folder and add this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

Then "npm run dev" *or* "yarn dev".

If you have the 'next dev' running when you define a new path, make sure to restart 'next dev'.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the fragments here. JSconfig and absolute paths are supported with all modern iterations of Next.js.

1. Create the configuration file:

   ```
   jsconfig.json
   ```
2. Specify you base URL:

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "baseUrl": "."
     }
   }
   ```
3. Change your imports like so:

   ```
   import 'components/header'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This seem to work for me in next v12.3.0

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

in component

```
import Navigation from "src/components/navigation/Navigation";
```

[image]