# Importing using absolute path in NextJs not working

Tags: node.js, next.js

I created a file in my route called jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

I have the latest nextjs `"next": "latest"`

Currently to import components, i have to do something like this:

```
import AppHeader from "../../../../components/common/AppHeader";
```

However with those changes above i thought I could do this:

```
import AppHeader from "src/components/common/AppHeader";
```

But I get this message:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'src/components/common/AppHeader'

Directory structure:

```
/
-->lib
-->src
   -->components
-->public
```

Any ideas?
I also tried adding this to my next.config.js file but also doesnt make a difference:
`config.resolve.modules.push(__dirname)`

Comment: Can I know about your folder structure? I guess you can try replace `src/components/common/AppHeader` by `components/common/AppHeader`

Comment: I updated my question with that. I tried what you mentioned and that says module not installed. I would also like to access things in lib using absolute paths.

Comment: I ended up just going with this solution using webpack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59542342/1009698 `config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve('./'))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using baseUrl in jsconfig.json not working with NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474480/using-baseurl-in-jsconfig-json-not-working-with-nextjs)

Answer (score 6):

Seems your folder structure is :

> root->src->components

add another property in your `jsconfig` file

```
{

   "compilerOptions": {
     "baseUrl": "."
    },
 
    "include":["."]

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those stopping by, this worked for me. Add this to your `tsconfig.json`.

**tsconfig.json**

```json
  "module": "CommonJS",
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@/layouts/*": ["src/layouts/*"],
    "@/components/*": ["src/components/*"],
    "@/public/*": ["./public/*"]
  }
```

Comment: tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json. The paths part of this answer helped my fix my issue. I declared every root path that was used in some import using the "@" for absolute.

Comment: "layouts" is misspelled

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that i had it outside the compilerOptions, now its working.

```html
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Next.js",
  "_version": "2.0.0",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    ".",
    "**/*.js",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use my tsconfig.json, it works for me:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

It also could be cause of running script if you running it in production mode
In my case i use:

```
"build": "nest build"
"start:prod": "node dist/src/main"
```

Answer (score -1):

Do following in **jsconfig.json**:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Now You can reach your folders like this:

```
src/components/..
src/lib/..
```

Answer (score -2):

Install @types with `npm install --save-dev typescript @types/react` command.

Your **tsconfig.json** file should be something like that:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@/public/*": [
        "public/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "."
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your configs, worked for me. Just stop and restart the nextJs server.