# What is jsconfig.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

If I search the same question on the Internet, then I’ll get only links to Visual Studio Code website and some blogs which implements it.

I want to know that is `jsconfig.json` is specific to Visual Studio Code or `javascript/webpack`?

What will happen if we deploy the application on [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services), [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku), etc. Do we have to make change?

Comment: According to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) it seems specific to VSCode

Comment: It's specific to VS Code.

Comment: It means we can not deploy it on cloud?

Comment: [anakha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68675994/what-is-jsconfig-json/68782883#68782883) and [Anson Kao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68675994/what-is-jsconfig-json/71666653#71666653) ***contradicts*** some of these comments and answers.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's a configuration file to assist your text editor. Your text editor's [Language Server Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) (LSP) looks into this file to learn more about your project.

While it appears this has originated from Visual Studio Code, any editor using LSP will make use of file *jsconfig.json*, including Visual Studio Code, [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) and so on.

It's most commonly used to include/exclude folders in your intellisense (which nowadays most editors use LSP), and map aliases in your source code to certain folders.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "$libs": ["src/libs"],
      "$libs/*": ["src/libs/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.svelte"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

This file basically tells the language server to:

#### baseUrl

Use the `.` location as the project root (which is where file *jsconfig.json*) is.

#### paths

It means *$libs* in your source code points to `/src/libs`. This is useful if your editor relies on LSP to locate the files. When you initiate *go to file* it will go to the right place.

#### include

It means to include all folders and files ending with those extensions in providing you with file search, code completion.

#### exclude

It means to exclude everything inside `node_modules` and `dist` folder. For instance, you don't want the compiled bundle to appear in search results when you are searching for symbols or variables.

#### Remarks

In other words, you can consider the *jsconfig.json* file a bit like the *.gitignore* file, but for your editor's language server use only.

But keep in mind, if you are going to be using *jsconfig.json* to map aliases, you would need to do additional configuration to your module bundler, and update your `eslint` config, that is, if you use [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint).

For instance, in a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) / [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) environment, you would need to tell your Node.js what *$libs* is. There are many ways to do so, but these days people mostly use *[module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)*.

Comment: why is the compiler option there? Found it: > Do not be confused by compilerOptions, since no actual compilation is required for JavaScript. This attribute exists because jsconfig.json is a descendant of tsconfig.json, which is used for compiling TypeScript

Comment: Adding `"$libs/*": ["src/libs/*"]` is really important, for me VS Code is not seeing aliases.

Comment: How can I work with "require" Node.js?

Comment: If you have a `tsconfig.json`, do you need this? Is there any point to having the paths etc. defined twice?

Comment: Silly question, if `jsconfig.json` is only used to assist editor, if I run npm build without relevant babel config, shouldn't my builds be failing (for things like aliases etc.) . Or is reading jsconfig also somehow baked into nodejs runtimes?

Comment: your module bundler (vite, esbuild etc) might (likely) also be relying on the jsconfig/tsconfig for certain settings. jsconfig and tsconfig is tightly coupled into the language server. When you run npm build (especially with react, svelte, vue etc), your project is compiled into a package. During this process jsconfig/tsconfig is consulted by your build process (as it was during your dev process).

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have noted, this protocol originated from Visual Studio Code - but has been adopted by many frameworks to work at compile-time:

#### Front-end

Front-end frameworks that support `jsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.json`:

- **Create React App** (see *[Importing a Component](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/)*)
- **Next.js** (see *[Using baseUrl in jsconfig.json is not working with Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474480/using-baseurl-in-jsconfig-json-not-working-with-nextjs)*)

#### Back-end

Back-end Node.js support for `jsconfig.json`/`tsconfig.json`:

- *[module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)*

Answer (score -2):

This is definitely specific to Visual Studio Code.

> The presence of jsconfig.json file in a directory indicates that the directory is the root of a JavaScript Project. The jsconfig.json file specifies the root files and the options for the features provided by the JavaScript language service.

Check more details in *[jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)*.

You don't need this file when deploy it on AWS or Heroku. Basically, you can exclude this from your commit if you are using a Git repository, i.e., add *jsconfig.json* in your *.gitignore* file. This will make your project IDE-independent.

Comment: If we add jsconfig into gitignore then we'll replace route `Components/User` into `../../../Components/User`in production?

Comment: It is not specific to vscode, vscode just uses it. it is in use with code compilers and all modern IDEs. iirc jsconfig was around even before vscode started. vscode just documents it well in context of vscode and seems like it's path resolver uses it.