# jsconfig.json Can't Work with "require" Node.js?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, commonjs

I'm studying the jsconfig.json file, the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) doesn't mention explicitly whether it works with "import" and "require", or just "import".

This is the jsconfig.json I created (for Express project):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es2020",
    "paths": {
      "@/controllers/*": ["controllers/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

I can't do like this:

```
const userController = require('@/controllers/user-controller');
// Error: Cannot find module '@/controllers/user-controller'
```

Why can't I use "require"? I Tried it in React and it worked with "import".

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with `require` vs `import`. Check that `@/controllers/user-controller` is installed in the Node project that that code is running in. Babel or a similar tool is likely compiling that module automatically with the React portion of your project.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68675994/what-is-jsconfig-json

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Because I have the same problem.