# VS Code Intellisense works for .ts files but not for .js files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase functions.
VScode doesn't show me errors and suggestions for .js files, but if I change the extension to .ts it works! I don't use TypeScript for my project.

Also, I use it alongside JavaScript for hosting and Intellisense works well!

I don't know, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a jsconfig.json file. For how to do so, see the following:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig
- [What is jsconfig.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68675994/what-is-jsconfig-json)